# How many different "views" does a RecyclerView use?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm having issues understanding exactly how the RecyclerView works. So the LayoutManager positions views within the RecyclerView and determines when to use item views that are no longer visible so how many different "views" does it create. For example, if I create a card view containing an ImageView and two TextViews and have a data source of say 20 objects to display into these cards, how many cards does the RecyclerView create? Since it's "recycling" views I wouldn't think it would create 20 at once since the user might only be able to see 5 at once on screen so does that mean it creates enough to fill the screen and populates them on the fly? I'm confused.

Comment: yes, it does creates on the fly (if that viewtype is not available on RecycledViewPool). You can test when RecyclerView is creating a new View by adding a log message to its adapter's onCreateView callback

Comment: Thank you kind sir! I added some logs and it makes a lot more sense now.